# Adwords: is it possible to automatically copy changes in one campaign to other campaigns?

Tags: google-ads

Is it possible to have identical campaigns except for one thing, and whenever changes are made to one campaign, the same changes are automatically made to others?

I want to have identical campaigns running for different time zones, but for the campaigns only to run between particular hours of the day in each time zone.

If I have a campaign for each time zone, when I make changes to one campaign, such as adding ad groups, or adding keywords, or changing bid amounts, etc, I want those changes to occur to the other campaigns also.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The best method to do this would be to use the adwords desktop tool. It won't automatically transfer changes but it does allow you to make bulk changes to your account. It would make it much simpler for implementing the changes across campaigns.

Answer (score 0):

Jaryd is correct but the thing you will probably need to search to find that tool is its name: "AdWords Editor."

It's a free download from Google.